# preg_replace not replacing certain matching strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to put a + in front of each word in a string, except when the word begins with a *.

Here's what I do to put the + in front of each word :

```
$string = "    *these are my words   ";
$trimmed = trim($string);
$pattern = '/ /';
$string2 = preg_replace ($pattern, ' +',$trimmed);
```

How do I avoid preg_replace to put a + in front of each word if that word has a * ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below negative lookbehind based regex.

```
preg_replace('~(?<!\S)([^*\s])~', '+\1', $str);
```

- `(?<!\S)` Matches all the boundaries which exists at the start of each word. Here word means one or more non-space characters.
- `([^*\s])` Matches a single character exists next to the matched boundary which must not be a space character or `*` symbol.
- Now it replaces the matched chars with the `+` plus the chars present inside the first captured group.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lU4oT6/2)

**OR**

```
preg_replace('~(^|\s)([^*\s])~', '\1+\2', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lU4oT6/4)